# GAWK - Multiple BEGIN and END sections

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I'm trying to process a bunch of files extracting data using gawk.

File area fixed width space formatted file

I'm trying to extract data from two different lines matched by two different regular expressions but return the data from both of these lines on the ONE print statement.

I can achieve this with the following in a`.awk` file and use `gawk -f` to run it. the first BEGIN section setup up input file format (FIELDWIDTHs) and the second BEGIN I am trying to use a loop per file to output based on extracted data. The first END complete the inner BEGIN and the second to match the outer BEGIN.

However I can only apply this to one file at a time because if I apply to a bunch of files (as in `gawk -f regex.awk km*.txt` , I only get the last file's output.

Can I get a one line of output per file input without having to resort to a script file looping over the input files and running the awk script each time.

Thanks

```
    BEGIN{
    OFS=","; FIELDWIDTHS ="2 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12";
                printf("Date,  Turnover, SalesA, SalesB, SalesC, SalesD, Other Data\n");
                }

    BEGIN{      Sales = 0;
                SalesA = 0;
                SalesB = 0;
                SalesC = 0;
                SalesD = 0;
                JointSales = 0;
                Turnover = 0;
                OtherData = 0;}

    /^03/ || /^06/ {

          if ($1 == "03") {
            Sales = $15/100;
            SalesA = $17/100;
            SalesB = $26/100;
            SalesC = $20/100;
            SalesD = $22/100;
            JointSales = SalesA - SalesB;
            Turnover = JointSales + SalesB + SalesC + SalesD; }
          else if ( $1 == "06") {
            OtherData = substr($0,183,12)/100; }

    #     printf("%s, %10.2f, %10.2f, %10.2f, %10.2f, %10.2f, %10.2f\n",  getDate(FILENAME), Sales, JointSales, SalesB, SalesC, SalesD, OtherData ) 
    }

    END{printf("%s, %10.2f, %10.2f, %10.2f, %10.2f, %10.2f, %10.2f\n",  getDate(FILENAME), Sales, JointSales, SalesB, SalesC, SalesD, OtherData ) }

    END {}


    function getDate(str)
    {   date = substr(str,3,6);
        year = substr(date,1,2);
        month= substr(date,3,2);
        day=substr(date,5,2);
        odate=(day"/"month"/"year);
       return odate
    }
```

Comment: What are you expecting multiple `BEGIN` and `END` blocks to be doing? You only get one of each. `BEGIN` runs at the start of the awk process and `END` runs at the end. If you are looking for ways to run things at the start and end of each processed file look at using `FNR`.

Comment: @EtanReisner no, you can have as many BEGIN and END sections as you like, it just doesn't make sense to put them all in one file. The time to use this is when you have several partial scripts stored in several files and you want to run a script that's the concatenation of all those files. I don't understand what the OP is trying to do though, he needs to post some sample input and expected output before he gets a solution that tells him how to implement whatever he's trying to do instead of how to do what he needs to do.

Comment: @EdMorton Indeed. rici corrected my misunderstanding in a comment below and yes, I can absolutely see the use of that in building up more complicated scripts from pieces now that I think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `gawk`, you're in luck. In addition to `BEGIN` and `END` blocks, `gawk` implements `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` blocks, which are executed just as you want: before and after processing each file. See the [handy gawk programming guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE).

Like all awk implementations, Gnu awk allows you to have multiple `BEGIN` and `END` blocks. All `BEGIN` blocks are run in order (first to last) before the first file is read, and all `END` blocks are run in the same first-to-last order after the last file is done. Since the same order is used for both types of special block, they don't "nest".

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to look into BEGINFILE and ENDFILE.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` only allows one `begin` and `end` action set per run (though they can be spread across multiple blocks, they're all combined into one action set) and a run includes *all* files that you process.

If you want to do something *between* each file as well, the can use the `ARGIND` variable which holds the index of the current argument (zero-based). You just need to maintain the last argument index (initially zero) and, if the *actual* argument index is different, execute your special actions and update the last index.

With empty files (for which no code would be run), the current argument index may be more than one higher than the last so you may need to *loop,* incrementing the last index until it reaches the current one.

For example, let's print the lines of each file but with special markers for before, within and after. With the file `a.in`:

```
xyzzy
plugh
```

and a `b.in` file containing nothing, you can use the following script `demo.awk`:

```
function middleCheck() {
    while (lastArgInd != ARGIND) {
        print "MIDDLE after "lastArgInd":"ARGV[lastArgInd]
        lastArgInd++
    }
}

BEGIN { print "BEGIN"
        lastArgInd = 1
}

{       middleCheck()
        print "   "$0
}

END {   middleCheck()
        print "END"
}
```

to effect an action *between* each file:

```
pax> vi demo.awk ; awk -f demo.awk b.in a.in a.in b.in a.in b.in b.in
BEGIN
MIDDLE after 1:b.in
   xyzzy
   plugh
MIDDLE after 2:a.in
   xyzzy
   plugh
MIDDLE after 3:a.in
MIDDLE after 4:b.in
   xyzzy
   plugh
MIDDLE after 5:a.in
MIDDLE after 6:b.in
END
```

You just have to make that action match what you need, your current "inner" `end` followed by your current "inner" `begin`.

Comment: Why bother with `baseNR`? Why not just check `FNR==1`? Or, since I think both of those will miss empty files, compare the previous `FILENAME` to the current `FILENAME` (or `ARGIND`).

Comment: @Etan, good point on that first item, I'll adjust answer since it's easier. However, since the normal `{}` only runs on an input line, I'm not sure a changed filename is any better - the `{}` won't be run in that case, yes? `argind` may well be better since it can detect empty files.

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure you can detect empty files in-line actually. Using `ARGIND` you can detect that you skipped them once you hit the next non-empty file though (and run X rounds of whatever your middle work is at that point). Though that also needs a check in `END` if you care about trailing empty files.

Comment: (and @EtanReisner): awk allows multiple BEGIN and END blocks. Conceptually, they are concatenated so you end up with a single initialization/finalization sequence, but it's misleading to say that you can only have one of each.

Comment: @Etan, yes, figured that out as well, so added the code for that. However, as per rici's answer, this may be overkill for GNU awk, which has BEGINFILE and ENDFILE that I wasn't aware of. I'll leave this answer here since it may still be useful for other less advanced awks but I suspect rici's should be the acceopted answer.

Comment: @rici, clarified that in the first para. Not sure if it's a waste given your excellent answer but we'll see what the swarm thinks :-)